# DynamoDB - Best approach to apply limit after scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm performing a scan function in a DynamoDB table and it's working very well. Now, I want to limit of results after apply filter.

I've read that when I combine a FilterExpression and Limit, DynamoDB will apply Limit then FilterExpression.

Is possible to do something inverse? First filter than apply limit? I'm trying to avoid do it on code because it will return more data than I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this in DynamoDB as it is not designed for such operations.

You can instead use LastEvaluatedKey for a simulated filtering of results, although that also will not be an efficient operation and can result in full table scan.

> A Query operation can return an empty result set and a
> LastEvaluatedKey if all the items read for the page of results are
> filtered out.
>
> To get the full count of items that match, take the LastEvaluatedKey
> value from the previous request and use it as the ExclusiveStartKey
> value in the next request. Repeat this until DynamoDB no longer
> returns a LastEvaluatedKey value.